# Querying a spreadsheet on Onedrive from Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-api, onedrive, excel-web-query

I share an Excel spreadsheet with some colleagues via Onedrive but we don't have any Microsoft BI tools. I'd like to use the Google Charts API to query some data from this sheet and present it in the form of a bar chart. Ideally the chart would change as we update the table.

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the Google documentation about querying non-Google data. The Onedrive API documentation is also quite confusing. Does anyone have experience with this?  Is there an easier way to do this other than SharePoint and other paid solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is Microsoft's Power BI. You can access the free Power BI service, load data from OneDrive, create charts other visualisations in reports, pin visualisations to dashboards.

You can share dashboards and reports with colleagues in the same domain. Power BI has apps for mobile platforms.

You can download the free Power BI for Desktop to design reports and publish to your organisation.

Some advanced features of Power BI are only available with a paid subscription, but the free version has more stuff than many people will ever use. Go to http://powerbi.com and have a look around.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought Power BI was an add-on to SharePoint. So we don't need an Office 365 subscription for this either?

Comment: No Office 365 subscription needed. All you need is a corporate email address, i.e. not a Hotmail or Gmail or other free public address.